# how to get the current consumed cpu % of vmhost in vcenter using powershell

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, vmware, cpu-usage, powercli

How to get the current consumed CPU% of vmhost in vcenter using powershell script.
Below command doesn't gives similar output what we checked manually.

Get-Stat -Entity $command1 -Stat cpu.usagemhz.average -Realtime -MaxSamples 1

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Stat -Entity $myHost -Stat cpu.usage.average -Realtime -MaxSamples 1 -Instance ""`

From VMware's [doc](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc/GUID-A6DA012E-D0CE-478B-9525-8B4703813542.html) on this cpu usage perf counter:

> Actively used CPU, as a percentage of the total available CPU, for
> each physical CPU on the host. Active CPU is approximately equal to
> the ratio of the used CPU to the available CPU.
>
> Available CPU = # of physical CPUs × clock rate.
>
> 100% represents all CPUs on the host. For example, if a four-CPU host
> is running a virtual machine with two CPUs, and the usage is 50%, the
> host is using two CPUs completely

[Explanations](https://www.lucd.info/2009/12/30/powercli-vsphere-statistics-part-1-the-basics) from Luc Dekens around the `-Instance` filter...

> If the ESX/ESXi server is equipped with a quadcore CPU, there will be
> four instances: 0, 1, 2 and 3. In this case the instance corresponds
> with the numeric position within the CPU core
>
> And there will be a so-called aggregate, which is the metric averaged
> over all the instances.
>
> These instances each get their own identifier which will be part of
> the returned statistical data. The aggregate instance is always
> represented by a blank identifier.

...and `-MaxSamples`

> Although I asked for 1 sample (-MaxSamples 1) the cmdlet returned 9
> values. The -MaxSamples parameter apparently only looks at the
> Timestamp. It doesn’t count the number of returned values